# Basic Laravel feature test running within Lando fails on get('/')

Tags: laravel, phpunit, lando

I am attempting to run the feature tests in a Laravel application which is running within a local Lando environment. The environment is accessible via https://catalog.lndo.site.

If I attempt to run the example test:

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_example()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

via the CLI with the command `lando php artisan test --testsuite=Feature` I get a failure:

```
• Tests\Feature\ExampleTest > example
  Expected response status code [200] but received 404.
  Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 404.

  at tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php:18
     14▕      */
     15▕     public function test_example()
     16▕     {
     17▕         $response = $this->get('/');
  ➜  18▕         $response->assertStatus(200);
     19▕     }
     20▕ }
     21▕ 


  Tests:  1 failed
  Time:   0.66s
```

I'm *assuming* this test isn't passing because it's running in a docker container.

If I follow the code through to `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests::call` I can see the request looks like this:

```
GET /catalog.lndo.site HTTP/1.1
Accept:          text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Host:            localhost
User-Agent:      Symfony
```

Obviously that GET url isn't correct

The .env file is:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
DUSK_DRIVER_URL=http://chromedriver:4444/wd/hub
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=catalog.lndo.site
APP_KEY=base64:VsA/HpgsJT1somemorestring=
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=database
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=laravel
```

Is there a configuration I can change in Lando, Laravel, or the test suite that would allow this test to pass? I can't help but think I just have a configuration value wrong somewhere

Comment: The issue is not that it is being run inside a docker, but some config. I am thinking about the `APP_URL`, can you share what do you have there?

Comment: Can you add your env file here? (remove the database and password parts)

Comment: @matiaslauriti I have added the .env file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have not added `http://` or `https://` to the begining of your `APP_URL`.

Due to how that is interpret, you must explicitly add the protocol to that ENV

Comment: That was it, thanks.  This app came to me so I needed to make some adjustments to the code after changing that but the test is now passing.

Comment: I am glad this solved your issue, if I remember correctly, this happened to me or a friend a long time ago, and it seems I did not forget about it